Why isn't generic type 'T' with constraint 'Enum' recognized as 'Enum' by interface?
internal interface IStateManager
{
    Enum State { get; }
}

internal abstract class StateManagerBase<TEnum> : IStateManager where TEnum : Enum
{
    public TEnum State { get; protected set; }
}

This throws:

'StateManagerBase' does not implement interface member 'IStateManager.State'.
'StateManagerBase.State' cannot implement 'IStateManager.State' because it does not have the matching return type of 'Enum'

In my understanding, when I constraint 'TEnum' to be of type 'Enum', the return type of 'TEnum' should be matching 'Enum'. My guess is I don't know a rule about generics/constraints.
Can anyone point me in the right direction?
EDIT: I accidentally declared State as nullable, its fixed to indicate the original intend now.

Enums are weird. System.Enum is a class, i.e., a reference type. Every useful instance of Enum is a value type. I'm pretty sure that when they finally added Enum as a constraint, something like TEnum? (where TEnum : Enum) would be interpreted as a nullable value type (but I don't know, whenever I use an Enum constraint, I mix in a struct constraint as well). There's a huge difference betwee nullable value types and nullable reference types. If you have to guess what the compiler will do with the code you've written, it's time to reconsider your choices

@Flydog57 Whoops, that was a mistake on my end. I also forgot the { get; } on the interface since I wrote this on the go without an IDE. But the problem persists without it being nullable.

This is just the rules of the C# language. Interface method implementations must match return type exactly; it's not a generics problem or an Enum problem. For example, this won't compile either for the same reason:
public class Foo {}
public class Bar : Foo {}

public interface A
{
    Foo X { get; }  
}

public class B : A
{
    public Bar X => new Bar();
}

The relevant part of the language specification is here - it says:

For purposes of interface mapping, a class or struct member A matches an interface member B when:

A and B are methods, and the name, type, and parameter lists of A and B are identical.
A and B are properties, the name and type of A and B are identical ...



Oh, I was assuming since Bar is of type Foo, it would fit the requirement for A. I was mistaken. Any insight on why this doesn't work? Is this not the entire point of inheritance? The child class inherits all properties of its parent ergo B returning Bar should work for interface A expecting Foo.

Added a link to the relevant language spec section.

Right.  C++ supports covariant return type of overrides, but C# does not.  enum is probably one of the motivating examples why C# does not... the calling convention treats System.Enum and User.E (where enum E : sbyte) completely differently and incompatibly.  C++ primitive types stand outside the inheritance tree, so covariance only ever applies to class types.

I can't reproduce the error.
But maybe this is better code.  Also State can be null.
internal interface IStateManager
{
    Enum State { get; }
}

internal abstract class StateManagerBase<TEnum> : IStateManager where 
     TEnum : Enum
{
    public TEnum? State { get; protected set; }

    Enum IStateManager.State => State; // Explicit interface implementation to satisfy IStateManager
}


I know this way I can get around the compiler error, but I just want to know why it doesn't work. Since TEnum is constrained to be of type Enum, just like what the interface wants it to return.
